# libgdx: The declared package does not match the expected package ""

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I'm working with LibGdx and Eclipse, I used the latest version and the setup tool that creates the project for Android, desktop and another one named "core", I imported in Eclipse, but I keep getting this error in both desktop and android projects:

The declared package "com.mygdx" does not match the expected package ""

[image]

Could you help me out please? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: How did you import it into eclipse? What is in the "source" tab of the build path menu for that property?

Comment: I imported it using Gradle. I got my-gdx-2dgame-desktop/assets and my-gdx-2dgame-desktop/src

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the src folder and select Build Path -> Use as Source Folder. Then restart Eclipse.

EDIT:
right click project -> Properties -> java Build Path -> Source -> Add Folder -> select src/

Basically eclipse is not able to descend your package tree correctly. After this refresh the project try a clean build.

Comment: Build Path only shows me -> Remove from build path, Configure output folder, Configure build path, Configure inclusion/exclusion filters. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies, I'm not currently at a computer with Eclipse so I was guessing. I edited the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone might find it useful, the actual problem was to add numbers in the project's name, that's why the package was splitted after com.mygdx, then the separate folders were created and gave me errors. I deleted this project, created another without numbers and that did the trick.

Thanks a lot for the help, still learning this libgdx + gradle!